# Is it possible to integrate Playwright-Javascript framework to azure devops pipeline?

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, automated-tests, devops, playwright

How to integrate Playwright-Javascript Framework with Azure DevOps pipeline for automating the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that you have to use two task

1. npm install
2. command line (script) (command = npx playwright test)